# sort chatter by most recent activity

Tags: chatter

Users are able to sort their chatter feeds by Post Date or Most Recent Activity.  Is there a way (code or settings change) that will force the change to Most Recent Activity for all active users currently sorting by Post Date?  I am not concerned if they change it back to Post Date afterwards.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm assuming you want to do this for all users. If so, this looks more like a Chatter Administrator use case. I don't think this is currently available via API or configuration setting.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently not a way for an administrator to do this for all users in their organization. There is no setting or API option. This is a preference (configurable in the UI only) that works on a per-user basis.